# How to keep File Input Box open and allow user input in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a html form where I need to enter multiple download paths.  I want to copy paste multiple paths from a , but I am forced to exit the file input box before I can paste entries into the form.  Is there a way to keep that file input box open, while also allowing me to type entries on my page?

Thanks